# How to stop an alarm in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In my main activity  which has a button in it. In its onclick listener im calling function  to set alarm.The alarm is working but iam not able to stop it .Can some one help me

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setalarm();
            }


        });
    }

    private void setalarm() {

        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        // cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,6);
        // cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2013);
        // cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,12);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,32);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mote.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent );
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm SET.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Mote.java:

```
public class Mote  extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Hello you have to take medicine I am Nitin Sharma";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
        CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";

        final int NOTIF_ID = 1234;
        NotificationManager notofManager = (NotificationManager)context. getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Alset.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText,when );
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notofManager.notify(NOTIF_ID,notification);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent i = new Intent(context,Alset.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
```

Alset.java:

```
public class Alset extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitystop); 
        Log.e("IM here ","Im here");

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(Alset.this, "Stop the alrm now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Once the alarm starts I will get the callback in the receiver's `OnReceive()` method. From there I'm going to the activity Alset where I kept a stop button. How do I to stop the alarm from here?

NOTE: - I'm hardcoding the time to set the alarm.

Comment: you need to cancel alarm from alarm manager try ====  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) _cntx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);   
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can cancel the alarm like this:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mote.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Also, you should remove `Intent.FILL_IN_DATA` from your call to `getBroadcast()` in the code where you set the alarm.

Comment: @droid_dev If you are having trouble please open a new question and post your code and explain what isn't working. The community can help you.

Comment: alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent) will just cancel the alarm from the alarmManager. it will not kill the fired activity. i have also raised the question to know how to kill the fired activity.  refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735209/android-repeating-alam-is-not-getting-stopperd-on-the-stop-button-clicked   pls reply if anyone know the answer

Comment: My initial intent add an action so for this to work I add to add the same action to the intent.

Comment: @Favolas yes, of course. You need to create a matching `Intent`, so the ACTION, CATEGORY, DATA and COMPONENT information must all match.

Comment: @DavidWasser Hey mate can you help me with a problem i have been having for 2 - 3 days, here's  my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950978/unable-to-set-proper-context-to-cancel-alarmmanager

Comment: can you please help me to fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267156/alarm-started-when-opening-the-app-instead-of-on-specific-time-in-android @DavidWasser

Answer (score 3):

you need to cancel alarm from alarm manager try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mote.class);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) _cntx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);          
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542099/cant-stop-the-ringing-alarm-from-another-activity#51542099 @user1140237