# Prevent alarm from going off when device is asleep

Tags: android

I've set a repeating alarm that I only want going off when the device is awake. When it's asleep, I want it to stop (and come back on when the device wakes up). However, it's currently going off no matter what. Here's how I register my alarm:

```
    Intent updateIntent = new Intent(UPDATE_INTENT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent updatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmService.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), UPDATE_INTERVAL, updatePendingIntent);
```

The alarm manager docs say that RTC will not wake up the device. The docs specify exactly the behavior that I want:

```
Alarm time in System.currentTimeMillis() (wall clock time in UTC). This alarm does not wake the device up; if it goes off while the device is asleep, it will not be delivered until the next time the device wakes up.
```

When I press the lock button on the device, I clearly see the going to sleep message from PowerManager in logcat:

```
I/PowerManagerService(488): Going to sleep by user request...
```

And then my alarm goes off anyway. What's going on here?

Ironically, every other question I've found on SO deals with alarms NOT going off while the device is asleep. I wish I had their problem!!

Comment: What is the value of `UPDATE_INTERVAL`?

Comment: For testing purposes I have it on 10 seconds (10000). But in production it will be a few hours.

Comment: Have you tried testing it with maybe 2 or 3 minutes? It's worth trying to rule things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually decided to register broadcast receivers to listen for SCREEN_ON, and SCREEN_OFF, and toggle the alarm appropriately. I realize this might not be super elegant, but at least it always works even if another app is holding a wake lock.

Listening for screen on and off: [android: broadcast receiver for screen on and screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477922/android-broadcast-receiver-for-screen-on-and-screen-off)

Turning off an alarm: [How to stop an alarm in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615986/how-to-stop-an-alarm-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

> However, it's currently going off no matter what.

Presumably something else is holding a partial `WakeLock`, and the device is not actually asleep, even though the screen may be off. Use **`adb shell dumpsys power`** to try to track it down (look for the "Wake Locks" section).

Comment: Here's the wakelock section:
Wake Locks: size=0

Suspend Blockers: size=2
  PowerManagerService: ref count=0
  PowerManagerService.Broadcasts: ref count=0

Comment: @Adam: Hmmm... AFAIK, the "ref count=0" pieces mean that those suspend blockers are not keeping the device awake. Can you try your code on another environment, such as an emulator?