# Alarm keeps ringing even if i press the stop button

Tags: android, ringtonemanager

I made an alarm clock, it works almost correctly except that it never stops.
Even i press my stop the alarm button it keeps ringing.

I have two buttons, one with id *setthealarm* and another with id *stopthealarm*.

In public class `MainActivity` I define `TimePicker`, `PendingIntent` and `AlarmManager`

```
public class activity_mainnew extends Activity {
TimePicker alarmTimePicker;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainnew);
alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
}
```

setthetime `onClick`:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void setthealarm(View view){
        Toast.makeText(activity_mainnew.this, "ALARM ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        long time;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getMinute());

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        alarmTimePicker.setDescendantFocusability(TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

        time = (calendar.getTimeInMillis()-(calendar.getTimeInMillis()%60000));
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()>time)
        {
            if (calendar.AM_PM == 0)
                time = time + (1000*60*60*12);
            else
                time = time + (1000*60*60*24);
        }
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 10000, pendingIntent);
    }
```

And stopthealarm `onClick`:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void stopthealarm(View view){
    Toast.makeText(activity_mainnew.this, "ALARM OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    pendingIntent.cancel();
}
```

in my AlarmReceiver class i have the following:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

        if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }

        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();
    }
}
```

Any idea please why ringtone doesn't stop?

Comment: have you tried `ringtone.stop();` when you want to stop it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop an alarm in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615986/how-to-stop-an-alarm-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly cancel your alarm you need to have your PendingIntent use the `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Also add a request code line in your AlarmReceiver class at the beginning, before the `onReceive()`:

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 222;
```

To stop the ringing call `stop()` on the ringtone when the stop button is clicked:

```
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
ringtone.stop();
```

Comment: I tried everything without luck... can you adjust your code into mine please nick?

Answer (score 0):

It just might be because you haven't pasted the code in this question but i dont actually see the code that connects *stopthealarm* to the button onclick. Are you sure the *stopthealarm* function triggers?

You do it for *setthealarm*, but not for *stopthealarm*

```
setthetime onclick:
```

Kind Regards

Comment: I forgot to write it.. button functions are working both