# Unable to set proper Context to cancel alarmmanager

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-context, android-pendingintent

I have created an alarm with a notification and a button to stop the alarm but it seems that there is some issue with the `Context`that I have to get in order to cancel the `AlarmManager`.

I have researched a lot and I think I have applied most of the things I found but somehow can't get this to work.

I am aware the `PendingIntent` has to be the same and it appears to me they are with the same request codes too.

AlarmSlave.class - Sets Alarm

```
 public class AlarmSlave /*extends Service*/ {

    private static final String STOP_ACTION = "STOP";

    private int hourOfDay;
    private int minuteOfHour;


    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    public AlarmSlave() {

    }
AlarmSlave(int hour, int minute) {

        hourOfDay = hour;
        minuteOfHour = minute;

    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        /*Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);*/
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 327, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteOfHour);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        Log.d("Ctx setAlarm ", context.toString());

    }
```

AlarmReceiver.class - Plays Ringtone Pretty Much.

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent){

        /*MainActivity inst = MainActivity.instance();

        Log.d("Testing","this is here"+inst);*/

        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmUri == null){
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        }

        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();


        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), AlarmService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(componentName)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

AlarmService.class - This is what shows the notification, the content intents are working fine but for the action they are not.

```
    public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

    public static final String STOP_ACTION = "STOP";

    public AlarmService() {
        super("AlarmService");
    }


    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        sendNotification("Wake Up! Wake Up");
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...:" + msg);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 327, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmActivity.class), 0);
        int notificationId = 1; // just use a counter in some util class...
        PendingIntent dismissIntent = AlarmActivity.getDismissIntent(notificationId, getApplicationContext());

        /*Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmSlave.class);
        stopIntent.setAction(STOP_ACTION);

        PendingIntent stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 10, stopIntent, 0);*/

        NotificationCompat.Builder alarmNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle("Alarm")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg)
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round, "STOP", dismissIntent);

        alarmNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(dismissIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(1, alarmNotificationBuilder.build());

        Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification Sent");
    }
}
```

ContextApp.class - This is what generates `Context` for me.

```
public class ContextBitchApp extends Application {

 private static Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getContext(){
    return mContext;


   }
}
```

Pardon for some of the language in the naming, done out of utter frustration after trying several different things over the period of two days.

EDIT: This is what my `Log` is showing for `Context`

```
05-13 09:37:55.208 24235-24235/<omitted> D/Ctx setAlarm: <omitted>.ContextBitchApp@7709bb7
05-13 09:41:18.760 3244-3244/<omitted>:remote D/Ctx onReceive: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@2c317d9
05-13 09:41:18.760 3244-3244/<omitted>:remote D/Ctx cancelAlarm: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@2c317d9
```

EDIT: Updated Code

Comment: May I know why you are not using 'ctx' as context again in 'cancelAlarm()' as you do in 'setAlarm()'? In my opinion that's the only problem.

Comment: @kushgupt In the `AlarmService`class I have called the `Context` form `AlarmSlave` to try to have the same `Context` but the log still returns different.

Comment: Okay,( so what I have learnt so far from your code), I think the problem with your code is that you are using different kind of context, like you are using `getApplicationContext` in your `public class ContextBitchApp` and used that @`setAlarm()` method of `public class AlarmSlave` class, but I didn't see what context you use for `cancelAlarm`, clearly it's not the same application context. So this means you are creating two different Intent which results in different pending intent, and ultimately you cannot cancel the same alarm. This is my opinion.

Comment: So have a look at his question:  [When to call activity context OR application context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

Comment: @kushgupt I am using the same way to get context just that I am passing a copy of the same Context from `AlarmSlave` to `AlarmService`, I am retrieving from `ContextBitchApp` and passing the same to `AlarmService` through `AlarmSlave` using the `getAlarmSlaveContext()`

Comment: can you try 'ctx' context in 'cancelAlarm()'? I believe it will sort out your problem and you can easily do that since they are both the members of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 0 instead `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and cancel method work fine, Try to use 0 in both intents or try to set `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` to the pending intent in your `private void cancelAlarm(Context context)` method.

Answer (score 0):

All your mucking around with `Context` is causing your problem.  You absolutely positively cannot do this:

```
private static  Context ctx = ContextBitchApp.getContext();
private static final Context ctxCopy = ctx;
```

a `static` variable gets initialized when the class is loaded. At this time, you have no idea what `ContextBitchApp.getContext()` will return.

In any case, you don't need to try to save `Context` and all that. Just always use `getApplicationContext()`  when you need a `Context` to pass as a parameter to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

Also, after calling `AlarmManager.cancel()`, you can also cancel the `PendingIntent` by calling `cancel()` on it.

Comment: `Can't resolve method 'getApplicationContext()'` is what it is showing me in `AlarmSlave.class` ,

Comment: If you are calling this from `onReceive()`, use `context.getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: @4127157 Were you able to figure this out? What is the status of your problem?

Comment: I have updated the code, please have a look, I can send you the .ZIP too if you'd like that. 

The alarm notification is going but the ringtone is not and not sure if alarm is cancelling now or not.

Comment: And what does `PendingIntent dismissIntent = AlarmActivity.getDismissIntent(notificationId, getApplicationContext())` do? You didn't show that code.